# Mysql Datevalue()=Date()

Tags: mysql, date, view, syntax

I'm trying to split a table in two views depending on whether the field "Date" is today or not.

I have tried using

```
WHERE DATEVALUE(`table`.`Date`)=DATE()
```

but I get an error at saving saying that the last ) has wrong syntax. I tried adding a group by, but apparently everything after the ) gives me the same message about wrong syntax.
Am I typing something wrong? Can I fix this? Is there maybe another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition you're looking for is:

```
table.`Date` = CURDATE()
```

if you column is of `DATE` type or

```
DATE(table.`Date`) = CURDATE()
```

if it's of `DATETIME` type

Answer (score 1):

You should try WHERE table.date = DATE( -your date- ). For instance:

```
WHERE table.date = DATE('1977-10-20') ;
```

Answer (score 1):

your function usage is wrong:

```
WHERE DATE(table.Date)=CURRENT_DATE
```